# I cant move imported objects to the centre

Tags: objects

I cant move them to the centre, i have to move the imported object to following coordiantes to get it kinda into the middle: x=200, y=-500 and z=0 but when i move it, the middle curser thing (where the cube was before) moves too and it isnt in the middle anymore. Idk why my imported objects are connected with the middle cursor thing but yeah. And i kinda start to frustrate and i dont want to use blender anymore, way to hard for beginners... but answers are appriciated ! THX!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Blender Stack Exchange! Just to clarify: by "middle cursor thing" you mean the little orange dot? It might be, that your objects origin ("center") is offset from the geometry. Try to select your object, press right-click > Set Origin > Origin To Geometry.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The solution depends on what importer you are using, but this is usually because the model's origin isn't set to its geometry.  Try selecting the model in object mode, right click and select origin to geometry.  I guess that "the middle cursor thing" is the object origin yellow dot?  Or is it the 3D cursor?  Anyway, a screen shot of an imported object before you try to movement and an indication of what importer you're using would help us answer your question.